# Ethernet connection not working on Ubuntu 20.04 / 20.10

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, 20.10

Hello Ubuntu community,

there is a weird issue with my wired internet connection that I didn't manage to resolve so far. I have an SSD running windows with working ethernet and I have recently installed Ubuntu on my new SSD. When switching between them I physically unplug the other. I've had other Linux distros (Mint, etc.) running on this setup in the past, so technically ethernet should work on Ubuntu as well. The mainboard, a Z97 HD3, is supported by Ubuntu and internet does work when I just boot from the USB. Couple different installations were tried so far minimal/normal with and without third-party drivers and both Ubuntu versions 20.04 and 20.10 (also Pop_OS with no success). The leds next to the lan cable are blinking as usual and speed tests have shown me speeds over the specified 100 mbit/s in the past. The router does support DHCP too, but I have also tried setting it up manually with no success. I have also reseted the profile couple of times by now but it didn't help either. What could be the reason for my internet not working on my installed setup and how can I fix this?

```
sudo lshw -C network
   *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 0c
   serial: 40:8d:5c:83:5a:5e
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@3:1
   logical name: usb0
   serial: 62:a7:2d:a1:44:46
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes
```

I have also installed the net-tools and checked this:

```
ifconfig
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 40:8d:5c:83:5a:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 3097  bytes 298814 (298.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3097  bytes 298814 (298.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.42.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
    inet6 fe80::9640:ddcf:a17a:2d2a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 62:a7:2d:a1:44:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 39490  bytes 46135485 (46.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 28413  bytes 4749210 (4.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to Settings-Network. With the Ethernet, wire plugged in, on the Wired section, toggle the switch on. Click on the little gear next to the switch and make sure that "Connect Automatically Lil peep [half](https://peepmerch.store/lil-peeps-hairstyles/) pink half-black" is toggled on.
Click the network connection or Wi-Fi icon on the panel at the top-right corner of your screen to access the NetworkManager menu, then choose a network. If you need to view information about your connection for troubleshooting purposes—your computer's IP address, for example—click Connection Information.

Comment: Hello James,

the "connect automatically" was always left toggeled on.